# Ruby regex to match a space without a leading comma

Tags: ruby, regex

How can I match a space without a leading comma?

My use case is I would like to split a string on space without a leading comma e.g. `"id 10, 11"`

Comment: without a leading comma? you could `string.split(%r{\s})`

Comment: Yup so basically for a string `"id 10, 11"` I only care about "id 10".  After splitting I would end up with `["id", "10"]`

Comment: Josh Brody, it splits on every space: ["id", "10,", "11"]

Comment: What if there are two spaces after `,`? Should it split on the second space? Also, see https://ideone.com/XTcSsP. Your question is too unclear. Please explain the expected output for the given example string, and why it should look like that.

Comment: Without an idea of what you're looking to get as output, this is very confusingly worded. Also you haven't attempted to solve the problem, so I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 2):

You need a [lookbehind regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2973495/3323777):

```
 'id 10, 11'.split(/(?<=[^,])[ ]/)
```

Output:

```
=> ["id", "10, 11"]
```

Comment: what if only want `=> ["id", "10"]`

Answer (score 1):

No need for a regex, just split twice:

```
"id 10, 11".split(",").first.split #=> ["id", "10"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the regular expression

```
r = /(?<!,) /
```

which reads, "match one space not preceded by a space" (`(?!,)` being a *negative lookbehind*).

```
"fe, fi, fo and fum".split r
   #=> ["fe, fi, fo", "and", "fum"]
"fe, fi,     fo\nand fum".split r
   #=> ["fe, fi, ", "", "", "", "fo\nand", "fum"]
```

If one wishes to break on one or more spaces not preceded by a comma, use

```
r = /(?<!,) +/
"fe, fi,     fo\nand fum".split r
  #=> ["fe, fi, ", "fo\nand", "fum"]
```

To split on one or more whitespace characters not preceded by a comma, use

```
r = /(?<!,)\s+/
"fe, fi,     fo\nand fum".split r
  #=> ["fe, fi, ", "fo", "and", "fum"]
```

It may prudent to first perform [String#lstrip](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-lstrip).

```
r = /(?<!,)\s+/
" fe, fi,     fo\nand fum ".split r
  #=> ["", "fe, fi, ", "fo", "and", "fum"]
" fe, fi,     fo\nand fum ".lstrip.split r
  #=> ["fe, fi, ", "fo", "and", "fum"]
```

Depending on requirements, one could instead take @elyvn's advice and write

```
r = /(?<=[^,])\s+/
```

which reads, "match one or more whitespace characters preceded by a character other than a comma" (`(?<=[^,])` being *positive lookbehind*).

```
" fe, fi,     fo\nand fum ".split r
  #=> [" fe, fi, ", "fo", "and", "fum"]
```